# Mysql varchar column suffix zero for integer value

Tags: java, mysql

Database  : mysql
Programming :- Java

I am trying to import excel into mysql database through java code. For the columns whose datatype is varchar values goes with point(.) zero at the end. I don't want to insert this kind of values instead to insert actual values.

screenshot for excel below.

[image]

screenshot for mysql database.

[image]

[image]

Screenshot for table structure.
[image]
Thank you in Advance.

Java Code

```
ExcelUtility excelUtility=new ExcelUtility();
        try {
            int count = 0;
            if (!file.isEmpty()) {



                for (Iterator iterator = dataHolder.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    if (count == 0) {


                        if(input1_val.equalsIgnoreCase("dunning"))
                        {

                            System.out.println("In Dunning");

                            List list = (List) iterator.next();
                            Notice_No=list.get(1).toString();
                            Notice_Date=list.get(2).toString();
                            Agreement_No=list.get(3).toString();
                            Branch=list.get(4).toString();
                            Customer=list.get(5).toString();
                            Product_Code=list.get(6).toString();
                            Overdue=list.get(7).toString();
                            CBC_Charges=list.get(8).toString();
                            LPP_Charges=list.get(9).toString();
                            Total_Claim=list.get(10).toString();
                            OD_Days=list.get(11).toString();
                            Tenure=list.get(12).toString();
                            Loan_Amt=list.get(13).toString();
                            EMI=list.get(14).toString();
                            ADDRESS=list.get(15).toString();
                            CITY=list.get(16).toString();
                            STATE=list.get(17).toString();
                            PINCODE=list.get(18).toString();
                            Final_Model_No=list.get(19).toString();
                            Branch_Address=list.get(20).toString();
                            Date=list.get(21).toString();
                            REGION=list.get(22).toString();
                            ReF_No=list.get(23).toString();
                            Type=list.get(24).toString();
                            MobileNo=list.get(25).toString();
                            break;

                        }

                              if(input1_val.equalsIgnoreCase("lrn")) { 
                                  System.out.println("In LRN");



                                List list = (List) iterator.next();
                                Ref_No = list.get(1).toString();
                                Notice_Date = list.get(2).toString();
                                Agreement_No = list.get(3).toString();
                                Customer_Name = list.get(4).toString();
                                Customer_Address = list.get(5).toString();
                                STATE = list.get(6).toString();
                                Zone = list.get(7).toString();
                                pincode = list.get(8).toString();
                                Product_Make_Model = list.get(9).toString();
                                Agreement_date = list.get(10).toString();
                                Tenure = list.get(11).toString();
                                Commencement_date = list.get(12).toString();
                                Last_Installment_Date = list.get(13).toString();
                                EMI = list.get(14).toString();
                                Arrear_of_monthly_installmentsEMI_debtorBroken_Interest = list.get(15).toString();
                                Interest_or_late_payment_charges = list.get(16).toString();
                                Cheque_bouncing_charge = list.get(17).toString();
                                Total_Charges = list.get(18).toString();
                                Future_installments = list.get(19).toString();
                                Termination_Charges = list.get(20).toString();
                                Total_Termination_Amount = list.get(21).toString();
                                State_1 = list.get(22).toString();
                                DPD = list.get(23).toString();
                                Branch = list.get(24).toString();
                                MobileNo=list.get(25).toString();
                                break;

                              }



                    }



                    count++;
                    //System.out.println("DataHolder :- " + dataHolder);
                }
                 response = ExcelUtility.updateToDatabase(dataHolder, jdbcTemplate,  input1_val);


                pdfbean.setStatusCode("200");
                //response = "File Successfully Uploaded";
                pdfbean.setStatusDesc(response);


            }
            else {
                pdfbean.setStatusCode("500");
                response = "File is Empty";
                pdfbean.setStatusDesc(response);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            response = e.getMessage();
            pdfbean.setStatusCode("500");
            pdfbean.setStatusDesc(response);
        }
```

Comment: Have you written any code? What is your question?

Comment: was about to ask the same

Comment: In database values are inserting like "1914966.0" but i want to insert "1914966" in the database. Though it will be alphanumeric values. Please check the screenshots for reference.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: MySQL stores the VARCHAR data strictly in a form in which this value is given to it. So edit `Agreement_No = list.get(3).toString();` code lines and remove excess chars (which may be added during convert from number to string).

Comment: @Akina...edited the line also done cast to it..getting the same. If I make text column in excel file and re upload then getting the desired result.